# DBFlow - inner join with another select statement

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, dbflow

I'm trying to convert the following SQL statement into DBFlow method calls:

```
SELECT t.SSID, t.BSSID, t.Latitude, t.Longitude, t.Timestamp 
FROM wlan_events t 
INNER JOIN (SELECT BSSID, MAX(Timestamp) AS MaxTimestamp FROM wlan_events GROUP BY BSSID) groupedt 
ON t.BSSID = groupedt.BSSID AND t.Timestamp = groupedt.MaxTimestamp
```

What I got so far:

```
SQLite.select(WifiEvent_Table.SSID, WifiEvent_Table.BSSID, WifiEvent_Table.latitude,
    WifiEvent_Table.longitude)
    .from(WifiEvent.class)
    .as("t")
    .innerJoin(WifiEvent.class) // ????
```

;

How do i create that inner join's select statement using dbflow?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found:

```
    SELECT EMP_ID, NAME, DEPT FROM COMPANY LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPARTMENT
      ON COMPANY.ID = DEPARTMENT.EMP_ID
```

in DBFlow:

```
SQLite.select(Company_Table.EMP_ID, Company_Table.DEPT)
  .from(Company.class)
  .leftOuterJoin(Department.class)
  .on(Company_Table.ID.withTable().eq(Department_Table.EMP_ID.withTable()))
  .queryList();
```

Hope this helps: (Link updated)

https://agrosner.gitbooks.io/dbflow/content/

Comment: Thanks but your answer doesn't have any select statement within the join

Comment: try using .on(new Select())